# Prevent AJAX Queue from blocking browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Note: simplified example..

I've got a page with 1000 table rows. For each row, i need to "do some work" on the server via an AJAX call, then in the callback, update that table row saying done.

Initially i tried just firing off the 1000 ajax requests inside the `.each` selector, but the browser was locking up.

So i changed it to try and use an internal ajax counter, so only ever fire off 50 at a time.

Here's the code:

```
$('#do').click(function () {
    var maxAjaxRequests = 50;
    var ajaxRequests = 0;
    var doneCounter = 0;
    var toDo = $('#mytable tr').length;

    $.each($('#mytable > tr'), function (i, v) {
        while (doneCounter < toDo) {
            if (ajaxRequests <= maxAjaxRequests) {
                ajaxRequests++;
                doAsyncStuff($(this), function () {
                    ajaxRequests--;
                    doneCounter++;
                });
            } else {
                setTimeout(function() {
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    });
});

function doAsyncStuff(tr, completeCallback) {   
    $.ajax({
        url: '/somewhere',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        complete: function () {
            completeCallback();
        },
        success: function (json) {
            // update ui.
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // update ui.
        }
    });
}
```

But the browser is still being locked up. It never goes into the `$.ajax` complete callback, even though i can see the request coming back successfully (via Fiddler). Therefore its just sleeping, looping, sleeping, etc because the callback is never returned.

I've got a feeling that the entire `doAsyncStuff` function needs to be asynchronous?

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong (or how i can do this better)?

Comment: This would probably be a lot more performant if you sent the request(s) in a batch. Via a single/fewer HTTP requests.

Comment: @Mythril - can't do that. each operation needs to independant. "why" is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Not a lot of good reasons to do that...So I'm still very curious why.. But  maybe you can use a html webworker?

Comment: I really can't believe that you need to fire a single ajax-request for each row - especially when firing them at the same time it's an indication that they could be bundled together. You really should overthink what you are doing. Nonetheless it would be a good thing to use a webworker for your ajax-calls. However you can't use jQuery for that but have to use native xmlhttp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a `while` loop inside the `.each` callback function, so there is much more ajax request than 1000, the worst is 1000*1000.

You could delay each ajax request with different time.

```
$('#do').click(function () {
    $('#mytable > tr').each(function (i, v) {
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function () {
            doAsyncStuff($this, function () {
               console.log('complete!');
            });
        }, i * 10);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser gets locked because of the WHILE... You are creating an endless loop.

The while loops runs over and over waiting for the doneCounter to be increased, but the javascript engine cannot execute the success call of the ajax since it is stuck in the while...

```
var callQueue = new Array();
$('#mytable > tr').each(function(key,elem){callQueue.push($(this));});

var asyncPageLoad = function(){
var tr = callQueue.splice(0,1);
$.ajax({
        url: '/somewhere',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: null,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        complete: function () {
            completeCallback();
            asyncPageLoad();
        },
        success: function (json) {
            // update ui.
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // update ui.
        }
    }
};
asyncPageLoad();
```

This will call the requests one by one. If you want, simply do a for() loop inside to make maybe 5 calls? And increase the amount if the browser is fine.

Comment: Note that this part of code is producing a weird error that I have been trying to track down for 3 days in IE7 and 8. The POST data is not sent with the request and although the server responds in a couple milliseconds, the browser waits for exactly 60 seconds before continuing. Happens at random on different calls.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I prefer to send new request when current request is done. I used this method to dump db tables ([in this work](http://qeremy.com/mydump/)). Maybe it gives an idea.

See [this link](http://qeremy.com/mydump/table_view.php?table=foo_blog_posts), check all check boxes and click Dump! button. And you can find the source codes [here](https://github.com/qeremy/mydump/blob/master/table_view.php#L302) (see `dumpAll` function).