# Browser freezing when updating backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am working with the facebook api, I am trying to update an existing model in my localstorage collection with some attributes from a facebook object.

```
fbUser: function(e) {
    var self = this;
    var faceid = $(e.currentTarget).data('face');
    FB.api('/'+faceid, function(response) {
        console.log(response.name)
        self.model.set({'name': response.name});
    });
}
```

The above works, but lags the browser up and causes a (not responding) "warning: unresponsive script" error.

This method executes on a click event within the view, I have another method that loads in a list of people from facebook and appends to the element. Let me show you that code.

I am loading members from a group. Then loading all those members and for each appending them as a list item with a custom attribute that contains their profile id.

```
loadFbMembers: function() {
    var self = this;
    FB.api('/554870764588961/members/', function(response){
      for (var i=0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
          FB.api('/'+response.data[i].id, function(response) {   
            var userImage = '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'+response.id+'/picture?width=32&amp;height=32" style="border-radius: 100em; width: 50px; height: 50px;">';
            self.$el.find('.test-list').append('<li class="fb-player" data-face="'+response.id+'">'+userImage+response.name+'</li>');
          });
      }
    });
}
```

I feel like this is obviously not ideal? I am not sure why this is causing so much lag.

Comment: I thought maybe I could try and set the value into an input and grab that value instead of passing the `response` directly in, but I tried passing a simple string `self.model.set({'name': 'jack'})` and it freezes, I may have to try and clean some things up and see if I can simply update with it crashing.

Comment: Do you have registered handlers for `change:name` event? Might there be recursion?

Comment: From what I understand you're asking if I register the event else where calling it multiple times? Sorry if I am a bonehead but I know I do not update the name attribute elsewhere, I update other attributes elsewhere. It's weird because It seems it's only with the name attribute because where I update other attributes they worked flawlessly then in the place of that attribute I try updating name and it freezes. I think maybe somewhere in my code I am relying on that attribute as a data-attribute. Let me try removing those and see what happens.

Comment: Okay I have narrowed down the culprit, it's either due to one of the following or perhaps all of them, but by commenting them out the model saves. `// this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.calculatePercent); 
            // Backbone.Regrettable.bind(this.model);                    
            // _.bindAll(this, 'on_keypress');
            // $(document).bind('keydown', this.on_keypress);`

Comment: Oh okay so when the model changes I listen to it, and run two methods `render` then I also listen for a change and run `this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.calculatePercent);` to calculate a percent, looks like I need to change that logic. I suspect it just causes a conflict.

Comment: Not a conflict but recursive `change` events are fired. Look at this code https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L363. See the `while` loop? Try passing `silent: true` like this `self.model.set({'name': response.name}, {'silent': true});`. You don't need to recalc percentage when `name` is changed.

Comment: Oh thanks that is actually very useful, I figured out a fix, but this definitely is something I can use thanks for that!!!!!

Comment: You should post your fix as an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent AJAX Queue from blocking browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154091/prevent-ajax-queue-from-blocking-browser)